# assign marking period name based on dates in table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with three columns: the start and end dates for each reporting period and the name of the period. I have a second table with a bunch of dates. I'm trying to create a third table that has the date from the second table with the name of the marking period from the first table.

I know I can do this by hard coding the dates from the first table into a bunch of CASE statements. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
select t1.SomeDate, t2.PeriodName 
from Table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.SomeDate >= t2.DateFrom and t1.SomeDate <= t2.DateTo
```

Comment: Oh, my, how embarrasing, I even used the same column name

Comment: @Lamak, it happens sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if you need all the dates in the table2 even where the corresponding name_period in table1 is null or all name_period in table1 where all the corresponding dates in table2 are null. However, try any of these:

1. create table table3 as select t2.start_date,t2.end_date, t1.period_name from table2 t2,table1 t1 where t2.start_date=t1.start_date or t2.end_date=t1.end_date;
2. Create table table3 as select t2.*,t1.period_name from table2 t2, table1 t1 where t2.start_date=t1.start_date or t2.end_date=t1.end_date;